# how can I make my toString to show the value with decimal in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Right now the string just shows as "234,234". This is the volume value. I need it to show the volume with a decimal but just 2-3 digits(like "234k")is fine.. Been at it for hours now... Any help is appreciated!

```
study("Vol", overlay=true, format=format.volume, precision=3)
```

.....

```
label1 = label.new(bar_index[rightbars], high[rightbars], text=tostring(volume[rightbars], ""), style=label.style_labeldown, color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.blue, 20))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.format()` or `round` + `tostring`  can do it:

```
//@version=4
study("Vol", overlay=true, format=format.volume, precision=3)

val = 234.234

str = str.format( "{0, number, integer}K", val)
// str = tostring( round(val, 0)) + "K"   // same

label.new(bar_index, high, str)

plot(close)
```

To add volume format (K/M/B)

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")


val = 123456789.12345

str = tostring(x, format.volume)

label.new(barstate.islast?bar_index:na, high, str)
plot(close)
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding "K" will hard code it, right? Volume can be dynamic and go from 0 to millions. Is there a way for it show the value as shown on a volume indicator? Example: 2k, 1.4m, 245k, 16.5m, etc

Comment: if you want to add M B K prefixes use this:

tostring(number, format.volume)
(added example above)